# get reference to project's base url in static resource file in Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

I have a bunch of static javascript files that handle AJAX functions to query various parts of my application, and I deploy multiple versions of my application, so I might have something along the lines of:

```
https://www.myurl.com/projectName/ - production release
https://www.myurl.com/projectName_alpha/ - current alpha release
https://www.myurl.com/projectName_beta/ - current beta release
https://www.myurl.com/projectName_unstable/ - current development build
```

so if I have a controller "foo" that I want to make an AJAX call to, I can't hard-code `/projectName/foo` as the URL (as that would always point to the production release).  Currently, I inject a script into each of my views that gets the base URL of the project as a global variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // declare a global variable to hold the project's base URL
    var baseUrl = '<spring:url value="/" />';
</script>
```

and then reference that in the javascript files:

```
var url = baseUrl + 'foo/';
```

It's functional, but an ugly solution, and I would rather not pollute the global namespace if I can avoid it.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could implement a better workaround?

To clarify: the solution should be workable for any type of request, whether it is AJAX-based or not - calling `window.open`, setting the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag, and making an AJAX call to a controller should all work with the solution.  It should also be applicable regardless of what the base URL is or how many layers deep it goes, eg:

```
https://www.myurl.com/
https://www.myurl.com/projectName/
https://www.myurl.com/projectName_alpha/1.2.3/
```

should all be detected properly.

Comment: what js lib are you using for ajax?

Comment: also having one global variable with well defined semantic isn't really 'polluting'. Almost certainly any other solution will be uglier than this.

Comment: I'm using jQuery for the AJAX.  You're probably right about alternative solutions being uglier; I'm just curious to see if anyone has an ingenious work-around.

Comment: from /projectName_beta/, can't you just fetch "foo" instead of "/projectName_beta/foo" ? relative urls work on script tags and ajax just fine...

Comment: If I fetch "foo", it references the current controller path, eg "/projectName_beta/controller/foo", which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that converting all your js files to jsps is not what you're looking for.

Obvious solution would be to use a module system ([require.js](http://requirejs.org/) for example) and wrap that value in a module,

Something like a jsp with:

```
define({
    baseUrl: '<c:url value="/" />'
});
```

which then can be required by other modules.

This however might need quite a big reorganization of your code code.

A simpler option would be to create a following jsp, included in every page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).ajaxSend(function (ev, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
            var context = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}';
            ajaxOptions.url = context + '/' +  ajaxOptions.url;
        });
    });
</script>
```

It prepends the context path to the url of each ajax-request made with jquery.

This should work as long as you use urls relative to the context (that is: starting with `/` , without the context name already) in your ajax requests.

Comment: I like the require.js idea, but it would require quite a substantial code reorganization on my project.  The AJAX suggestion is functional, but only works for AJAX requests (obviously); I forgot to specify in the question that it should work for any use of a URL (corrected now).  +1, and I'm inclined to award the bounty to you if no one else gives something better.

Comment: @asgaliant in that case you're kind of forced to have a global var/use require as any place of your js code can have `window.location` assignments and the like. Also js templates rendering becomes tricky as you have to make sure the templating engine has access to the url prefix in order to render the correct urls.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the ([JSTL core url tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm))?  We typically use `@RequestMapping(value="/foo")` combined with `var url = '<c:url value="/foo">'` and its not context-root sensitive.  Although it does take a parameter at the JSP level to change the context root if you need to rebase the script.

Comment: The problem is that you can't reference those in static js files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the global *location* object and regex

If you are in the alpha release, p.e. 
https://www.myurl.com/projectName_alpha/resource.html

You will retrieve the info from the *window.location* object

```
window.location.protocol = "https"
window.location.host = "www.myurl.com"
window.location.pathname = "/projectName_alpha/resource.html"
```

If you will extract, by splitting or by regex, the context root from the pathname, you can use that value to build the different URLs that you need.

If you will enrich the location object with a baseUrl property, you can access this easily in the page

```
window.location.baseUrl = window.location.pathname.split("/")[1];
```

And you can build your urls in this way:

```
var url = window.location.baseUrl + '/foo/';
```